# pass parameters to then chain in promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jsforce

I'm using JSforce to retrieve an Account Id, once the operation is completed, I need to pass the retrieved account's Id and another Map to another function.

```
testAsync();

function testAsync() {
    let myMap = new Map();
    myMap.set('abc', 1234);
    console.log('myMap.get(abc): ', myMap.get('abc')); // output: 1234
    conn.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 1")
        .then(function(res) {
            return res;
        })
        .then(function(res, myMap) {
            //console.log('in then:')
            console.log('res.records[0].Id::: ', res.records[0].Id) // output: 0011k00000oM4EZAA0
            console.log("myMap.get('abc')::: ", myMap.get('abc')) //this line isn't getting called
        })
}
```

How do I also pass myMap to .then function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .then(function(res, myMap) {
```

This causes the outer level map to be *shadowed*, which is why you can't reach it. Do not pass it in:

```
    .then(function(res) {
```

Also, you should probably use arrow functions instead, which makes it easier to access data outside of the function scope (as it shares this with its original scope):

```
    .then((res) => {
```

Comment: sorry sfdcfox but I'm not sure what should be changed from your comment, should I just use     .then(function(res) { /*logic*/}) ?

Comment: @Json Yes, the myMap can be picked up because of its lexical scope. No need to pass it in.